# Make AVPlayer to full screen view in AVPlayerViewController, Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am new to swift and getting problem in making AVPlayerViewController.player go to full screen in 
ViewController: AVPlayerViewController

here is code I am using in viewDidAppear to play the video

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType: "mp4")!
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    self.player = player
    self.showsPlaybackControls = false
    self.player!.play()
```

I am making playBackControlls hidden, and required to make video view to full screen...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For adding AVPlayer to a view, I make a CALayer from it like this:

`let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)`

Then you need to add this layer to a view, for example, if you wrote that code in a ViewController, then you can do this:

`self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)`

Next, make sure that this layer is as big as the parent ViewController:

`playerLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds`

And now, you can choose any of [these](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avlayervideogravity) options to how to resize your video. Here, I used `.resize` assuming aspect ratio of video and the screen are the same

`playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize`

Comment: @(Hamoon Jamshidi Meydandar) did you tried to have play controls with AVPlayerLayer to full screen?

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend following solution without adding extra layer:

in your **ViewController: AVPlayerViewController** in `viewDidLoad()` just set

```
videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
```

According to documentation:

> The video gravity determines how the video content is scaled or
>   stretched within the bounds of the player view controller’s view. The
>   player view controller supports the following video gravity values:
>
> - resizeAspect
> - resizeAspectFill
> - resize
>
> The default value is  **resizeAspect**.